# 1980s science fiction novel with two infertile protagonists (one an astronaut) and a "psychic vampire" antagonist

Tags: story-identification, novel, space, psychic

I am wracking my brain about a novel I read back in the '80s that I think was by Fred Saberhagen.

The first of the two main protagonists is an astronaut on the first deep space mission using suspended animation; he gets picked up by aliens who think this is a bad design for astronauts and rebuild his body leaving him with no ability to have children. The other protagonist is a woman who sold all of her eggs to escape the life she had been living.  The antagonist is a "psychic vampire" who brings them together to feed off of their mutual despair.

Does this sound familiar to anyone?

Comment: If anyone posts a correct answer, please consider marking it as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), which you can do by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons. It's this site's way of formally indicating that a query has been solved to the querent's satisfaction.

Answer (score 11):

Is this ***[Thorns](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/872291.Thorns)*** (1967) by Robert Silverberg...?

The Goodreads synopsis mentions two protagonists and an antagonist matching your description:

- Minner Burris, a space traveller whose body was taken apart and rebuilt by alien surgeons.
- Lona Kelvin, a woman whose who eggs were harvested by scientists.
- Duncan Chalk, a media mogul and "emotional vampire" who feeds off of other people's pain.

> **Duncan Chalk is a monstrous media mogul with a vast appetite for other people's pain. He feeds off it,** and carefully nurtures it in order to feed it to the public. It is inevitable that Chalk should home in on **Minner Burris, a space traveller whose body was taken apart by alien surgeons and then put back together again - differently.** Burris' pain is constant. And so is that of **Lona Kelvin, used by scientists to supply eggs for 100 children and then ruthlessly discarded.** Only an emotional vampire like Chalk can see the huge audience eager to watch a relationship develop between these two damaged people. And only Chalk can make it happen. First published in 1967

This is further expanded upon in the following [review](https://sciencefictionruminations.com/2011/01/26/book-review-thorns-robert-silverberg-1967/):

> Minner Burris, a spaceman, returns to Earth after captivity among a group of aliens — whose motives are never uncovered — horribly disfigured and modified.  His body chemistry has been changed, he has extra joints, peculiar eyes, a tentacle attached to his hand…  He hides in his room afraid that the world might see his face.
>
> Lona Kelvin, a 17-year old young woman, is psychologically scarred after a fertility experiment (I guess in the 60s in vitro fertilization was a shocker) that made her a mother of one hundred children yet still a virgin.  She never sees her children…  After the brief media sensation she retreats away from the world and attempts to commit suicide.
>
> **Enter, Duncan Chalk, a massively obese man who peddles pleasure and pain for the entertainment of millions.  He arranges for the two characters to meet and fall in love** — bribing each with vague promises: Burris will receive a new body and Lona will have at least some of her children back.

[image: Front cover of "Thorns" by Robert Silverberg.]